# Can not establish a pipe between processes

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I am trying to create a pipe between parent and child processes:

```
def launch_process():

    parentStdin, childStdout = os.pipe()
    childStdin, parentStdout = os.pipe()

    pid = os.fork()
    if pid:
        os.close(childStdout)
        os.close(childStdin)
        self.set_configuration()            
    else:
        os.close(parentStdout)
        os.close(parentStdin)
        os.dup2(childStdin, 0)
        os.dup2(childStdout, 1)            
        os.execvp("echo.py", "")
        raise RuntimeError

#after launch_process() call...
pipein = os.fdopen(parentStdin) #I saved both parentStdin and parentStdout variable as global
while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    os.write(parentStdout, ("command").encode())
    line = pipein.readline() #the program stops here
    print(line)
```

This code can launch a child process but `pepin.readline()` blocks running without any result. What's wrong?

**edit:** Child process runs the following loop echo-program ("echo.py"):

```
while True:
    value = input()
    print(value)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: echo is writing to a pipe instead of a pty so its block buffering the output not line buffering. Adding a flush after print to echo.py should fix it.

Comment: It should be easy to update this to a running example so we can all play along.

Comment: @tdelaney I updated my answer with code of echo.py, but there is flush fucntion for stdout and it does not work however

Comment: You also have to send newlines (e.g., write "command\n") from the parent.

Comment: Generally, if you want to interact with a child program, pipes opened with the `pty` module work better. Even then it can be dicey because a program may gather information from the controlling terminal and you may end up needing to emulate that also. The `pexpect` module can be helpful for this sort of task.

Comment: You commented _#I saved both parentStdin and parentStdout variable as global_, but the shown code does not do that. You'd have to present complete code.